# is nested function calling possible in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm using a script to call a separate file and inside that file I'm calling another file.

The script I'm using to call is this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#socials").load("sources/socials.html");
    });
</script>

<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#icon").load("img/icon.xml");
    });
</script>
```

and I'm calling the file like this:

```
<div id="socials"></div>
```

and inside socials.html, I'm calling the icon.xml like this:

```
<div class="email-bg">
            <a href="mailto:info@genericemail.com?" id="icon"></a>
        </div>
```

it's not working for me when I try it like this. Is it not possible to do or is this just the incorrect way?

**EDIT**
I explained it in a comment below so I'll include the comment here too, I think it makes a little more sense what I'm trying to accomplish:

Essentially I have two standalone files that I am referencing, file A and file B. I am referencing file B inside of file A. When I reference file A in index.html, it works fine except that file B will not get referenced and I don't see the content of file B. BUT if I reference file A and file B directly in index.html without referencing, I can see the content of both files as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` is asynchronous, and the second function isn't waiting for the first one to finish, so the `#icon` element isn't in the DOM when it runs. You need to do it in the callback function.

```
$(function() {
  $("#socials").load("sources/socials.html", function() {
    $("#icon").load("img/icon.xml");
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that's the issue because when I use id="icon" in the same file as the function, I can call the file as expected. The issue only arises when I try to access it in a nested file. Essentially I have two standalone files that I am referencing, file A and file B. I am referencing file B inside of file A. When I reference file A in index.html, it works fine except that file B will not get referenced and I don't see the content of file B. BUT if I reference file A and file B directly in index.html without referencing, I can see the content of both files as expected

Comment: That's because `$(function()...)` waits for the current document to be loaded. But it doesn't wait for AJAX calls.

Comment: ok I am beginning to understand now. so if I wanted to use file A to call files B and C would it look something like this:  `$(function() {
        $("#socials").load("sources/socials.html", 
            function() {
            $("#icon1").load("img/icon1.xml",
                function() {
                    $("#icon2").load("img/icon2.xml")
                });
            });
        });`

Comment: Yes. Anything that depends on what's loaded asynchronously from a particular file should be in the callback for that file.